# How can I use a class type as a map key in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to store some information in a TypeScript (JavaScript) map under a key which reflects the type of a class. This is because the stored data is actually static and applies per type, not per instance.

Here's how I have declared the Map atm:

```
private static followSetsByATN: Map<number, FollowSetsPerState> = new Map();
```

However, `number` should be a class type instead. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have an object (`{}`) as a map then the keys must be strings (or numbers which are converted to strings automatically).
In this case you can use the `toString()` method:

```
class A { }
console.log(A.toString());
```

Will print:

```
function A() {
    }
```

You can also use the `name` property:

```
console.log(A.name); // "A"
```

You can also override the `toString()` method to return something of your own:

```
class A {
    static toString() {
        return "class A";
    }
}
console.log(A.toString()); // "class A"
```

And then:

```
let m = {} as { [name: string]: string };
m[A.toString()] = "something";

// or
m[A.name] = "something";
```

If you are using a `Map` then all of the above still work, but you are not restricted to have string keys therefor you can use the class itself:

```
let m = new Map<{ new (): A }, string>();
m.set(A, A.toString());

console.log(m.get(A)); // "class A"
```

---

#### Edit

If you have an instance of a class, you can get the class using the `constructor` property:

```
let a = new A();
...
m.set(a.constructor, SOME_VALUE);
```

The [`constructor` property](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L100) comes from `object` and it looks like so:

```
interface Object {
    /** The initial value of Object.prototype.constructor is the standard built-in Object constructor. */
    constructor: Function;

    ...
}
```

So you always get a `Function` and you'll need to cast:

```
m.set(a.constructor as typeof A, SOME_VALUE);
```

As you probably don't know the type of the class, you'll need to do something else.
You can cast to `any`, but that's not very pretty.

Here's a working solution that should work well for you:

```
interface Base { }
type BaseContructor = { new (): Base };

class A implements Base { }
class B implements Base { }

let m = new Map<BaseContructor, string>();
let a = new A();
let b = new B();

m.set(a.constructor as BaseContructor, "value");
m.set(b.constructor as BaseContructor, "value");
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Base%20%7B%20%7D%0Atype%20BaseContructor%20%3D%20%7B%20new%20()%3A%20Base%20%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass%20A%20implements%20Base%20%7B%20%7D%0Aclass%20B%20implements%20Base%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Alet%20m%20%3D%20new%20Map%3CBaseContructor%2C%20string%3E()%3B%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20new%20B()%3B%0A%0Am.set(a.constructor%20as%20BaseContructor%2C%20%22value%22)%3B%0Am.set(b.constructor%20as%20BaseContructor%2C%20%22value%22)%3B))

Comment: That looks already very good. Now how to get the class type of an object (say: an instance of `A`)? Can you please add that too?

Comment: What do you mean by "class type of an object"?

Comment: `let a: A = new A(); myMap.set(a.class, myValue);` That **class** member is the open question. I usually don't have just classes, but various instances of a number of classes.

Comment: Hmm, that gives me an error: "Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => A'.
  Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature 'new (): A'" on the `myMap.set(a.constructor, myValue);` call.

Comment: Sorry about that. Check my answer again, I added a working version

Comment: It's worth noting that this approach won't work if you have classes with the same name, which could happen if they're imported from other files (`import {Foo as Bar}` doesn't affect `.name`. I just ran into  this issue myself because two libraries I was using defined their own `Node` classes for data structures.